# Error in code to upload file via php and html form

Tags: php, html, mysql, file-upload

I am experiencing an error with the following code whereby the file fails to upload to the server.  Can someone please take a look at the two files and advise where I have got it wrong, I know I have probably been thick but any help would be greatly appreciated.

The files are on a small internal intranet so I am not concerned with the fact I am putting the database connection and password into the file.

As I said any help would be greatly appreciated as I am only receiving the final sorry error and no information is being passed to the MySQL database.  I can get the form and code to work fine without the upload but not with.
I have checked the upload directory and permissions for access to it and all are ok.

the html form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="add.php" method="POST"> 
Model:<br /> <input type="text" name="model"><br> 
Size:<br /> <input type="text" name="size"><br> 
Total width:<br /> <input type="text" name="tot_width"><br>
Internal width:<br /> <input type="text" name="int_width"><br>
Total height:<br /> <input type="text" name="tot_height"><br>
Frame height:<br /> <input type="text" name="fra_height"><br>
Total depth:<br /> <input type="text" name="tot_depth"><br>
Seat height:<br /> <input type="text" name="sea_height"><br>
Seat depth:<br /> <input type="text" name="sea_depth"><br> 
Arm height:<br /> <input type="text" name="arm_height"><br>
Std leg height:<br /> <input type="text" name="std_leg_height"><br>
Image:<br /> <input type="file" name="image"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Add"> 
</form>
```

The PHP:

```
//This is the directory where images will be saved 
$target = "/images/product"; 
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['image']['name']); 

//Get all the other information from the form 
$model=$_POST['model'];
$size=$_POST['size'];
$totWidth=$_POST['tot_width'];
$intWidth=$_POST['int_width'];
$totHeight=$_POST['tot_height'];
$fraHeight=$_POST['fra_height'];
$totDepth=$_POST['tot_depth'];  
$seaHeight=$_POST['sea_height'];
$seaDepth=$_POST['sea_depth'];
$armHeight=$_POST['arm_height'];
$stdLegHeight=$_POST['std_leg_height']; 
$pic=($_FILES['image']['name']);

// Connect to Database 
mysql_connect("localhost", "databaseUser", "databasePassword") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
mysql_select_db("databaseName") or die(mysql_error()) ; 

//Write information to the database 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `prod_dims` VALUES '$model', '$size', '$totWidth', '$intWidth', '$totHeight', '$fraHeight', '$totDepth', '$seaHeight', '$seaDepth', '$armHeight', '$stdLegHeight', '$pic'") ; 

//Put the image on the server 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['name'], $target)) 
{ 

//Is the upload ok 
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and     your information has been added to the directory"; 
} 
else { 

//Give an error if its not 
echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['name'], $target))
```

to

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target))
```

Comment: Great stuff.  Always frustrating when you stare at something for ages and look straight through the obvious error :)